# Autoclicker for Ubuntu

Tags: permissions

I've tried to search many places for an autoclicker

I need one to use it in a game.

And I found one here:
From [Murguu](http://www.murguu.com)

I downloaded it, but I have no idea how to install

It states that it is for Ubuntu, but I'm new to this and don't know what to do.

Also, I tried some forum answers and got to know that by changing the permission of the AutoMouseClick.sh to "Allow executing file as Program" but it always unchecks itself every time i check it. It doesn't let me change anything from the "Permission" Tab

Please help -

Thanks

Edit

My Ubuntu Version is 12.04 Linux SUPERFAST 3.8.0-35-generic #52~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:24:40 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

---

Yeah! Got it!

I don't know how it worked but it's working now.

I had extracted it in a Drive called "Storage" and used to launch.

Now, instead of putting it anywhere, i just extracted it on Desktop and Launched

It's not working

Thank you all for your support!

Thanks a lot :D

-Jack

Comment: It's not something that you need to install. What happens if you drag and drop AutoMouseClick on a terminal, and append `chmod +x ` to the front of the line before pressing Enter?

Comment: Thanks for replying @madharuhi. I did that and append chmod +x. But nothing happened. It still doesn't let me change the "Permission" Tab.

Comment: Are you the root user of that system? If you can, run `gksu nautilus` and try to change the permissions from there.

Comment: Ah....I've no idea what to do. I did go to Terminal and typed gksu nautilus. It prompted for password and I entered it in. Next it opened up Home Folder (This is quite weird because, i can't see My Drives to the left).

Comment: Hmm try this instead: Open the folder where AutoMouseClick is and go to File>Enter Location, copy that location, do `gksu nautilus` but this time with the location pasted behind it (eg. `gksu nautilus /home/ubuntu/Documents/LinuxAutoMouseClick`)

Comment: Did that, and still can't change the "Permission" Tab. Same thing happening.

Got this message with wine, with numerous error by Terminal
[ErrorImage](http://imageshack.com/a/img24/4051/h3c2.png)

Comment: Thanks for the help :D, now it's working. Extracted it to desktop and launched. Worked :D Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you have correctly downloaded the package at 
http://www.murguu.com/linux-auto-mouse-click/download/32-bit/LinuxAutoMouseClick.zip (32-bit) or 
http://www.murguu.com/linux-auto-mouse-click/download/64-bit/LinuxAutoMouseClick64Bit.zip (64-bit) ?

Extract the package once you downloaded it by right clicking on the package and selecting 
`extract here`

The folder after extraction should look like this:
[image]

Now all you have to do is double-click the `AutoMouseClick` file and the program should start.
[image]
(Tested just now) 
 
If these steps don't work please edit your post to tell us which version of ubuntu you are using and also append the output of the command `uname -a`

Comment: Thanks for replying Daniel. To be sure, i re-installed the link you provided Deleting the one I've downloaded. But still It didn't solve the problem.

Still neither can i open the program nor change the setting in "Permission" Tab

My Ubuntu Version is 12.04

Linux SUPERFAST 3.8.0-35-generic #52~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:24:40 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

That was the output from uname -a


Also, I've downloaded the 64-bit one

Here are 2 pictures of what happened

[link](http://imageshack.com/a/img829/1333/39zk.png)

[link](http://imageshack.com/a/img132/1010/23d8.png)

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your support. I extracted it to desktop and launched (usually had it in one of the Drives called "Storage") Thanks alot :D

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. I click on 32bit and 64bit, but the download never begins. It just refreshes the page.